# Avoid hough transform

Tags: image-processing

This is my first question here!

I have found the Hough Transform method not very robust to noise. Can I totally avoid it and efficiently find lines in the image?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi & welcome to SO! You should revise your question according to the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- for instance, what software are you using, what does you code look like, how exactly does _not robust to noise_ show up in your results, etc.

Comment: I disagree. In most cases HT is very robust to noise. show some example iamges that cause you problems

Comment: @patrick Understood!

Comment: @Piglet I concur!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various edge detectors that provide more general output than lines, such as the [Canny edge detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector).  With suitable processing, this can give you 'edge chains' made of 'edgels'.  From there, you can do some analysis of the edge chains to split it into line segments (generally based on looking for 'kinks' in the chain to identify corners.)  This can be a fairly noisy process too, though, and there are lots of different kinds of heuristic criteria you might use to refine your set of lines further.

In general, the Hough Transform is a first-pass that gives you a (noisy) set of candidate lines in the image and is suitable when you don't know where lines might be.  From there, you need to do further analysis of your candidates to determine which match what you're actually looking for.  Like most problems in computer vision, the details of how you actually apply these basic tools depends very much on what you're attempting to analyze.

Comment: are you suggesting a more efficient/robust pre-processing step(s)? I was thinking to use MSER https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions . And you are also saying there is actually no alt to Hough Transform, yes?

Comment: @VickyBudhiraja, The edge detector and edgel chain construction approach is an alternative.  There are lots of other options as well.  Without knowing more about the kind of images you want to analyze, exactly what you mean by finding lines and exactly what you mean by 'noise', it's hard to say more.  The Hough transform is not very sensitive to shot noise, for instance, but it might still be 'noisy' if you have a lot of edges in your image that can combine to form unwanted lines.